# Problem with read and write functions in c++

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

I am facing problem with read and write functions in C++ and C also.

When I input 2 or more `name` and `id`s in my code it writes it perfectly to the file but when I read the file with `fread` it show some weird behavior it prints same value of `id`s as I enter for different inputs but for name it prints the same string for all inputs with different length which I entered last.

Example:

Input:

```
2     
aaa 1      
bbbb 2
```

Output:

```
ID 1 Name bbb
ID 2 Name bbbb
```

It should print like:

```
ID 1 Name aaa
ID 2 Name bbbb
```

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct person 
{ 
  int id; 
  string fname; 
}; 

int main () {
             
    FILE *outfile;
    struct person input; 
    int num,ident;
    string sname;        
    
    outfile = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\students.txt","w+");
    
    if (outfile == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n"); 
        exit (1); 
    } 
    
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    
        cin >> sname;
        scanf("%d",&ident);
    
        struct person student = {ident,sname};
    
        fwrite (&student, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile);
    }
    
    fseek(outfile,0,SEEK_SET);
    
    while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile)) {   
        cout << "ID " << input.id << "  Name " <<input.fname << endl;
    }
           
    fclose (outfile);       
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any answer in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to indent it properly :)

Comment: Try to use ofstream and getline in C++

Comment: And don't tag spam. If you're coding C++, tag it C++

Comment: You cannot use `fread` and `fwrite` with structs that contain `std::string` objects. Use an ifstream and ofstream and perform line-based IO correctly.

Comment: It shows weird behavior because a std::string likely has internal pointers to memory allocated on the heap. You can't save and restore such an object the way you are doing because the pointers will be invalid when you restore and you are not saving the data that the pointers point to.

Comment: You may wan't to read about this topic: [https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: PS, please don't use `bits/stdc++.h`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816096/201787).

Comment: Not to mention [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932).

Comment: Also, `scanf()` of (potentially malformed) input without checking return code -> undefined behavior waiting to happen. Your `num` and `ident` may be used uninitialized.

Comment: Please reply what should I do now to solve this problem

Comment: Serialize your class using text instead of binary serialization. You probably also want to move to use `c++` iostreams instead of fread / fwrite. The link I gave above on serialization explains your options.

Comment: When using binary I/O, my suggestion is to write the text size first, followed by the text.  This allows you to allocate the string variable correctly (since you know the size), then read in the text using block reading.  This same concept can be applied to variable length fields.